# Related Rates increasing or decreasing distance of 2 trains at specific instant

Tags: calculus

I'm looking for another set of eyes to help me find if the distance between two trains is increasing or decreasing.

*Problem*

> At a certain instant, train A is 4 miles west of a station, going east at 20mph while train B is 5 miles north of the same station, going north at 15mph. At this instant, is the distance between the trains increasing or decreasing? At what rate?

After drawing a diagram and finding the derivative for the Pythagorean Theorem, I haven't been able to find if the distance between the two trains is increasing or decreasing.

*Work*

$$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$
$$4^2 + 5^2 = \sqrt{41}$$
$$\sqrt{41} = 6.403$$
$$2a\frac{dA}{dt} + 2b\frac{dB}{dt} = 2c\frac{dC}{dt}$$ 
$$\frac{dC}{dt} = \frac{2a\frac{dA}{dt} + 2b\frac{dB}{dt}}{2c}$$
$$\frac{dC}{dt} = \frac{2(4)(20) + 2(5)(15)}{2(6.403)}$$
$$\frac{dC}{dt} = 48.415$$

*Conclusion*

I would like to guess that the distance is shrinking because train A is moving faster and closing a shorter distance than train B. I am unable to back up that guess. Is there any way I can find the proper answer with the information given?

Comment: You should use $\frac{dA}{dt}=-20$, it's getting closer to the station.

Comment: So by substituting it with a negative, I get a much smaller dC/dt which would be -0.781. Would this proper answer? Since I don't have the time elapsed the best I can get is the -0.781? @WW1

Comment: The question asks about the rate of change at the instant described, so there should be no elapsed time. My calculations agree with yours -0.781 mph

Comment: @WW1 I see what you mean now. Thank you. How do I close this question or marked it as solved?

Comment: @Jacq You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the exact instant, make $\frac{dA}{dt} = 20$ a negative. Which will yield -0.781 as the correct answer at that instant.